# Delphi Berlin 10.1 create file/folder OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

How to create file/folder on OS X via delphi? 
I'm trying to use functions

```
System.SysUtils.FileCreate
```

And

```
System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory
```

Code:

```
  if FileCreate('/var/folders/bla.txt') = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
 raise Exception.Create('File already exists');
```

or

```
 `TDirectory.CreateDirectory('/var/folders/mydirdelete');`
```

Anyway when i run app i get

```
Exception EFileNotFoundException in module blprtl240.dylib at 0053AFAF.
The specified file was not found.
```

Even if i create folder.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs says [FileCreate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.FileCreate) return **INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE** (**-1**) indicates that an error occurred which not only mean that file already exists e.g. it could be **Permission denied** ...etc.

Regarding [CreateDirectory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory) raises an exception if the given Path is invalid or contains invalid characters.

Try this instead:

```
const
  AFilename = '/tmp/folders/bla.txt';
begin
  if NOT FileExists(AFilename) then begin
    if NOT DirectoryExists(ExtractFilePath(AFilename)) then
      if NOT ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(AFilename)) then RaiseLastOSError;
    if (FileCreate(AFilename) = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
```

Comment: @artemk **EFileNotFoundException** raised only if the specified file doesn't exist. The above code will never raise such exception.

Comment: Thank you. i've got it. Good luck!